# Selecting a random key from a dictionary so it can displayed

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I want to use a random key from the dictionary to blit, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
# This is a skeleton code for small interactive programs using PyGame
# interaction is handled in main() in a structured way.
# "while true" has four main elements:
# 1) declaring the STATE variable (and other useful variables)
# 2) the event loop:
#     - which only cycles if new events arrive
#     - which contains the interactive transition conditionals
# 3) a number of ATCs, handling the automatic transitions
#     - are continuously checked to allow for timing conditions
# 4) a number of drawing conditionals


# Development Information
# TODO: change ITC from E-S-E to E-E-S

import pygame
import sys
from time import time
import random
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.compat import unichr_, unicode_


# Colors
col_white = (250, 250, 250)
col_black = (0, 0, 0)
col_gray = (220, 220, 220)
col_red = (250, 0, 0)
col_green = (0, 200, 0)
col_blue = (0, 0, 250)
col_yellow = (250,250,0)
BACKGR_COL = col_white

SCREEN_SIZE = (700, 500)

# Preparing the PyGame window
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Skeleton")
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
screen.fill(BACKGR_COL)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 80)
font_small = pygame.font.Font(None, 40) 


def main():
    # Variables
    STATE = "welcome" ## list, possible, states

    # screen refresh loop
    while True:
        # setting the background color
        pygame.display.get_surface().fill(BACKGR_COL)        

        # event loop (is only entered when an event occured)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # Interactive transition conditionals (ITC)
            if STATE == "welcome":
                if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
                    STATE = "prepare_next_trial"
                    print(STATE)
            # always include transition for quit events
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        # automatic transition conditionals (ATC)
        if STATE == "prepare_next_trial":
            screen.blit(mydict['sp1'],(248,148))

        # Drawing conditionals
        if STATE == "welcome":
            draw_welcome()
        pygame.display.update()
        # Picture dictionary


    # end screen refresh loop

# define draw functions and other functions
def draw_welcome():
    text_surface = font.render("STROOP Experiment", True, col_black, BACKGR_COL)
    text_rectangle = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rectangle.center = (SCREEN_SIZE[0]/2.0,150)
    screen.blit(text_surface, text_rectangle)
    text_surface = font_small.render("Press Spacebar to continue", True, col_black, BACKGR_COL)
    text_rectangle = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rectangle.center = (SCREEN_SIZE[0]/2.0,300)
    screen.blit(text_surface, text_rectangle)

mydict = {'sp1': pygame.image.load('smartphone1.jpg'),
          'sp2': pygame.image.load('smartphone2.jpg'),
          'sp3': pygame.image.load('smartphone3.jpg'),
          'tb1': pygame.image.load('tablet1.jpg'),
          'tb2': pygame.image.load('tablet2.jpg'),
          'tb3': pygame.image.load('tablet3.jpg')}

# RUN
main()
```

This is the error i get:
return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
KeyError: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Apparently, ``mydict`` was empty at the time you tried to pick a random image from it.  What you posted is obviously not a complete program, the problem is likely in an area you didn't post.  Note that you're calling ``screen.blit`` with the dictionary *key* ("sp1", etc.), NOT the image.  Also, it's rather inefficient to reload all of your images each time through the loop!

Comment: Hey Jasper, thanks for looking at my problem. Ive updated the post with my full program. I did put the dictionary out of the loop, thank you for that tip :)Though, I'm still getting stuck, do you know what i need to do to blit a random image from mydict (or another sort of container?)

Answer (score 0):

solved it

```
# This is a skeleton code for small interactive programs using PyGame
# interaction is handled in main() in a structured way.
# "while true" has four main elements:
# 1) declaring the STATE variable (and other useful variables)
# 2) the event loop:
#     - which only cycles if new events arrive
#     - which contains the interactive transition conditionals
# 3) a number of ATCs, handling the automatic transitions
#     - are continuously checked to allow for timing conditions
# 4) a number of drawing conditionals


# Development Information
# TODO: change ITC from E-S-E to E-E-S

import pygame
import sys
import time
import random
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.compat import unichr_, unicode_


# Colors
col_white = (250, 250, 250)
col_black = (0, 0, 0)
col_gray = (220, 220, 220)
col_red = (250, 0, 0)
col_green = (0, 200, 0)
col_blue = (0, 0, 250)
col_yellow = (250,250,0)
BACKGR_COL = col_white

SCREEN_SIZE = (700, 500)

# Preparing the PyGame window
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Skeleton")
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
screen.fill(BACKGR_COL)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 80)
font_small = pygame.font.Font(None, 40) 


def main():
    # Variables
    STATE = "welcome" ## list, possible, states

    # screen refresh loop
    while True:
        # setting the background color
        pygame.display.get_surface().fill(BACKGR_COL)        

        # event loop (is only entered when an event occured)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # Interactive transition conditionals (ITC)
            if STATE == "welcome":
                if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
                    STATE = "prepare_next_trial"
                    print(STATE)
            # always include transition for quit events
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        # automatic transition conditionals (ATC)
        if STATE == "prepare_next_trial":
            screen.blit(random.choice(picture_list),(248,102))
        # Drawing conditionals
        if STATE == "welcome":
            draw_welcome()
        pygame.display.update()
        # Picture dictionary


    # end screen refresh loop

# define draw functions and other functions
def draw_welcome():
    text_surface = font.render("STROOP Experiment", True, col_black, BACKGR_COL)
    text_rectangle = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rectangle.center = (SCREEN_SIZE[0]/2.0,150)
    screen.blit(text_surface, text_rectangle)
    text_surface = font_small.render("Press Spacebar to continue", True, col_black, BACKGR_COL)
    text_rectangle = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rectangle.center = (SCREEN_SIZE[0]/2.0,300)
    screen.blit(text_surface, text_rectangle)

# picture list
picture_list = []    
SP1 = pygame.image.load("smartphone1.jpg").convert()
picture_list.append(SP1)
SP2 = pygame.image.load("smartphone2.jpg").convert()
picture_list.append(SP2)
SP3 = pygame.image.load("smartphone3.jpg").convert()
picture_list.append(SP3)
SP4 = pygame.image.load("tablet1.jpg").convert()
picture_list.append(SP4)
SP5 = pygame.image.load("tablet2.jpg").convert()
picture_list.append(SP5)
SP6 = pygame.image.load("tablet3.jpg").convert()
picture_list.append(SP6)
SP7 = pygame.image.load("laptop1.jpg").convert()
picture_list.append(SP7)
SP8 = pygame.image.load("laptop2.jpg").convert()
picture_list.append(SP8)
SP9 = pygame.image.load("laptop3.jpg").convert()
picture_list.append(SP9)
# RUN
main()
```